# What exactly are smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contracts

I'm new to Tezos, and in fact to Bitcoin in general.  I have been reading up on it a good bit, though, and I ran across an article [on cryptobriefing](https://cryptobriefing.com/tezos-gets-new-life-in-a-rare-second-chance/) which states that Tezos, like Ethereum, uses smart contracts.

What exactly is a smart contract - and how does it compare with a "dumb" contract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A smart contract is a small script that is directly stored and executed on the blockchain by bakers for Tezos (and miners in a POW setting).

Smart contracts enable users to handle tokens, derivative tokens (as in ERC20 contracts), conditions, events, etc., in an explicit and automatic way.

A 'dumb' contract is a regular contract written on a piece of paper without the automatic execution.
Also smart contracts need to be fully explicit whereas regular contracts leave a lot to interpretation.

A nice primer by the CFTC, a US regulator:
https://www.cftc.gov/sites/default/files/2018-11/LabCFTC_PrimerSmartContracts112718.pdf

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the 'explicit' nature of smart contracts a bit more?

Comment: Explicit means that the code of a smart contract is public and stored on the chain which has two consequences: it is readable by everyone and it is directly followed in a deterministic way by bakers.